# Tracking PDF downloads thank you pages

Tags: analytics

I want to track PDF downloads that take place on my site. I understand I have to create a Google Analytics goal to track conversions. I understand that I have to provide GA the URL of the "thank you" page I want to track. If I have 5 different PDFs, do they each need their own unique URL "thank you" page? Or can I use the same thank you page for all and still be able to drill down to how those visits perform over time by specific URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single URL and then assign specific events for each download.

Note that GA cannot track a PDF download as a page view, since the PDF itself cannot hold Analytics code. Instead, you have to track clicks on the download link. Google have provided a pretty useful guide to tracking such "additional" events:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012044?hl=en